# C# WebBrowser send Mouse Click Event to Flash Object

Tags: c#, .net, flash, mouseevent, webbrowser-control

I've been reading around but didn't seem to find an answer to this question. The objective is: I have a `WebBrowser` in a Windows Forms Project. There is a HTML page loaded, and in that HTML page there is a Flash Object. My goal is to send a Mouse Click to (x, y) positions of that Flash Object.

**The (desired) Requisites**

- The window with the Windows Forms executable doesn't need to be active in order for this to work
- The mouse must not be captured
- Send a mouse click based on coordinates (x, y), relative to the Flash Object or the Web Page

**Example**

Imagine I open any Tower Defense game in the WebBrowser. I want to simulate clicks to buy and place new towers. During the proccess the user must not loose control of the mouse. If at pixel (x, y) = (30, 50) was a button and I wanted to click that button, I could just by calling something like `WebBrowser.simulateLeftClick(30, 50)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = false)]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr GetWindow(IntPtr hWnd, uint uCmd);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern int GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpClassName, int nMaxCount);
```

Class can be defined by means of `Spy++`

```
public static void MouseClick(int x, int y, IntPtr handle, string Class)
{
    StringBuilder className = new StringBuilder(100);
    while (className.ToString() != Class)
    {
        handle = GetWindow(handle, 5);
        GetClassName(handle, className, className.Capacity);
    }

    IntPtr lParam = (IntPtr)((y << 16) | x);
    IntPtr wParam = IntPtr.Zero;
    const uint downCode = 0x201;
    const uint upCode = 0x202;
    SendMessage(handle, downCode, wParam, lParam);
    SendMessage(handle, upCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

WebBrowser handle

```
IntPtr handle = webBrowser1.Handle
```

Comment: The language of SO in English. Please use it next time.

Comment: please tell me about "Class can be defined by means of Spy++" elaborate it please.