# C# Awesomium - Send click event to flash game

Tags: c#, flash, mouseevent, awesomium

I'm trying to make a program that loads a webpage with a flash game on it in Awesomium WebControl, and then can click on a button in the game.

I've viewed a few google should-be-solutions just trying to get the flash handle and click at a specified point, but it doesn't seem to be working. Here's what I've morphed:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = false)]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr GetWindow(IntPtr hWnd, uint uCmd);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern int GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpClassName, int nMaxCount);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr parentHandle, IntPtr childAfter, string className, IntPtr windowTitle);

public IntPtr Flash()
{
    IntPtr pControl;
    pControl = FindWindowEx(webControl.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, "Shell Embedding", IntPtr.Zero);
    pControl = FindWindowEx(pControl, IntPtr.Zero, "Shell DocObject View", IntPtr.Zero);
    pControl = FindWindowEx(pControl, IntPtr.Zero, "Internet Explorer_Server", IntPtr.Zero);
    pControl = FindWindowEx(pControl, IntPtr.Zero, "MacromediaFlashPlayerActiveX", IntPtr.Zero);
    return pControl;
}

public static void FlashMouseClick(int x, int y, IntPtr handle)
{
    IntPtr lParam = (IntPtr)((y << 16) | x);
    IntPtr wParam = IntPtr.Zero;
    const uint downCode = 0x201;
    const uint upCode = 0x202;
    SendMessage(handle, downCode, wParam, lParam);
    SendMessage(handle, upCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

And then I'm calling this like:

```
FlashMouseClick(200, 310, Flash());
```

Now, I've mixed a few things here, such as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183146/c-sharp-how-to-postmessage-to-a-flash-window-embedded-in-a-webbrowser) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21176778/c-sharp-webbrowser-send-mouse-click-event-to-flash-object) and probably in a bad way, but I also tried each as they were and neither worked. As the code is, nothing happens when I call the Click function. Any idea where I'm going wrong or have a better way to do it?